# How to filter repeated logs with Winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

This is an example what I have in the log file:

```
log 1
log 2
log 2 
log 2
log 3 
log 4
```

And this is what I want to have:

```
log 1
log 2
log 3
log 4
```

How can I filter repeated new logs?

Comment: You can keep a set of logged messages in memory but that can easily become a performance bottleneck for your application when it runs out of memory. Why do you want to filter repeated logs? 
What is the volume of your logs?

Comment: Repeated logs makes analysis more complicated. The script runs every 2 sec. It makes log file too long.

Comment: If the log size is a problem, did you consider log rotation instead?